# I am losing precision when converting from float to varchar

Tags: sql-server, variables, precision, varchar

I am working on Sql Server 2012.

I have 2 tables:

```
Create table tbl1 (formula varchar(50))

Insert into tbl1 values ('A-B')


Create table tbl2 (A float(53), B float(53))

Insert into tbl2 values (12.2466654, 11.7543289)
```

I am trying to get the result as variable `@result`:

```
Declare @result varchar(250);
Declare @a varchar(50);
Declare @b varchar(50);

Select @a = a from tbl2;
Select @b = b from tbl2;

Set @result = replace(tbl1, 'A', Cast(@A as float(53));
Set @result = replace(tbl1, 'B', Cast(@B as float(53));
```

When I select from `@result` I get something like `12.2-11.8` so it is almost good but I am losing precision.

Maybe you have an idea how to write the query correctly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is there a reason you can't use Decimal instead of float?  There is the possibility of precision loss with float.

Try using STR() instead of CAST() when converting to to VARCHAR().  This comes from the Converting float and read data on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173773.aspx

```
DECLARE @result varchar(250);

SELECT @result = STR( tbl2.A, 10,8) + '-' +  STR( tbl2.B, 10,8)
  FROM tbl2;

 PRINT @result;
```

This resulted in the string "12.2466654-11.7543289" for me.

Comment: Wel I think in this case I can create intermediate table with columns in decimal format and import all data from tbl2 there. And then work with data from new table

Comment: Are you looking for the value in tbl1 to be 0.4923365 or to be the string '12.2466654-11.7543289'.  If it's just the string, then using STR() should solve the problem [STR( tbl2.A, 10,8) + '-' +  STR( tbl2.B, 10,8)].  If you're looking to get 0.4923365, you're going to need to need to account for the loss of precision of the float datatype.  To demonstrate the lack of precision, when I do [CAST(12.2466654 as float) - CAST(11.7543289 as float)] I get back 0.492336499999999 on my SQL Server 2012 instance.

Comment: I need to represent it as a string! Will try Str() tomorrow! Thank you for your help